# Whats the architecture behind signed / locked bootloaders (i.e. for android)?

Tags: android, cryptography, bootloader

i know that for example Motorola used to sign their bootloaders for der Milestone/Droids which made it quiet hard for the modding scene to apply their costum roms.

My question is how does this work on an abstract level?
I guess it might be like this:

1. The manufacturer (i.e. Motorola) puts its public key into smartphone's EEPROM/non-volatile memory (NVM)
2. The bootloader is signed with the manufacturer's private key
3. Upon device start, the bootloader somehow checks it's own signature with the help of the public key, loaded from the eeprom/NVM
4. Only, if the signature is correct, the bootloader proceeds.

a) So, if this would be correct, how does step 3 really works? How could a signed application check it's own signature?

b) I guess there is some other piece of code running before the signed bootloader, but isn't the bootloader the first programm to run? (Apart from startup.S)

Hope someone could enlighten me as I only find definition of what signed bootloader means but not how this is really implemented.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of modern chips have a [mask ROM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_ROM) that executes before any user-provided code ever runs.  It's this ROM, immutable and embedded into the chip itself, that does the initial signature checks.